# Быстро вставить 1 000 000 значений в mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Есть такая задача.
БД MySQL в ней одна таблица `(int)`, и нужно заполнить значениями с `1` до `1 000 000`.
Подключаюсь и работаю с БД через `jdbc`.

Мне приходит на ум два решения: придумать запрос на формирование такой таблицы и передать его в БД через `statement`, или можно сделать типа цикла в `java` и записать значения через цикл.
Допустим:

```
for(int i=1;i<=1000000;i++){
  // запрос на добавление одного нового значения.
}
```

Собственно вопрос, как сделать такую вставку быстрее?
В задаче важна скорость. Есть у кого идеи?

Comment: Попробуйте через цикл, я думаю, не много времени должно занять. Либо создайте процедуру и запустите её.

Comment: http://www.programering.com/a/MDM3gTNwATU.html

Comment: @Denis https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674951/182273

Comment: И да, если делаете через цикл обязательно пользуйтесь подготавливаемыми запросами, т.е. перед циклом один раз делаете prepare на что то типа `insert ... values(?,?,?)` (возможно в java нужны не `?` а что то другое), а в цикле только выполняете этот запрос привязывая/передавая очередные данные

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Оптимизация**:
Можно в одном запросе добавлять сразу несколько строк.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE v < 20 DO
    INSERT `table_name` VALUES (v+1),(v+2),(v+3),(v+4), /* 50000-4 values */;
    SET v = v + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Выполни сохраненную процедуру

```
CALL dowhile();
SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
```

При таком варианте 1 000 000 строк добавятся за 14 секунд. 1000 итерации c 1000 values – 74 секунды. 100 по 10 000 строк – 22 секунды.

Можно в одном запросе все миллион строк добавлять. То есть можно и через JDBC такой запрос послать, ограничение на длину запроса в MySQL 32 МБ вроде.

**Неактуальная информация**: Создай хранимую процедуру

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 1;
  WHILE v1 <= 1000000 DO
    INSERT `table_name` VALUES (v1);
    SET v1 = v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Добавление 1000 записей заняло у меня 47 секунд, то есть 1 000 000 записей добавятся за 13 часов.